# OMNeT++/Veins: Why WSM message is sent/broadcasted ONLY for the first accident scheduled?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am doing some simulations using the Veins framework (with the RSU scenario). I defined two accidents for node[*0] as shown in the code below. However, node[*0] sends WSM message to neighboring nodes (i.e., vehicles and RSU) **only** for the first accident. When it arrives to the second accident, it stops for a while but does not send any message. I further tested this by scheduling more accidents, but the message is still sent/broadcasted only for the first accident. My question is, why node[*0] is not sending WSM message when it arrives to each of the other scheduled accidents? I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me clarifying this issue. Thank you.

```
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 2
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 60s
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 40s
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentInterval = 70s
```

Answer (score 0):

The application used in the Veins example simulation is https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L96. As you can see, it uses a `bool` member to track whether it has already sent a message and, if it has, refuses to send another.